# Remove top and right Border in Column 2D fusion charts

Tags: fusioncharts

I am trying to remove top and right border alone when using column 2D fusion charts [chart is rendered using javascript].
When Show border is 0 , it removes entire border.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the border property of the container HTML element of your chart. You should do this after FusionCharts has successfully rendered itself (`rendered` event). Hide all borders of the chart (`showBorder = 0`)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the attached image will suit your requirement?[image]